# receive wrong bytes values over socket stream in java

Tags: java, sockets, stream, arrays, byte

I try to read a file as a byte array and send it through network over socket connection,
I printed the values of the bytes after reading from file(before sending it) and printed the values of bytes after receiving it from socket ... and it was different! it is received in wrong values I don't know why

sample bytes before sending:
21,
0,
52,
0
sample bytes after receiving:
-8,
-1,
-4,
-1

I sent the bytes using write(byte[] b); of OutputStream class
and received bytes using read(byte[] b, int off, int len); of InputStream class.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Voo is expressing frustration at the lack of information.  It's possible that you're making a mistake that someone might immediately recognize - if they saw your source code.  Did you try reading more than 4 bytes?  I suspect that what you read has nothing to do with what you wrote - it's something else entirely - but I don't know what it is, either.

Comment: As voo and ed said, we need more to go on than that.  Create a small test program, the smallest you can that reproduces the problem, and post it.  I just made a quick test program that sends and receives those bytes using the same methods, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Does this network connection occur between different operating systems? That is could this be an endianess issue?

Comment: You are not doing what you think you are doing.  There is no way the bytes can be changing the way you suggest, the values are not signed and endianess doesn't matter here

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
Socket c = new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort());

byte[] bytes = {21, 0, 52, 0};
c.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
c.close();

byte[] bytes2 = new byte[4];
Socket s = ss.accept();
ss.close();

new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()).readFully(bytes2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes2));
s.close();
```

prints

```
[21, 0, 52, 0]
```

Comment: Interesting! Without reading the javadocs, I'd have assumed that your code would deadlock when the `c = new Socket(...)` waited for the `s = ss.accept()` that followed it.  I guess it didn't :-)

Comment: @Adrian Pronk No, it's all asynchronous. You could move all the client code up to and including c.close() in front of the accept() and it would still work.

Comment: @EJP, I would assume you have to `s = ss.accept();` before `s.getInputStream()` ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Of course otherwise there's no `s`, but that's server side code. All the stuff involving 'c' can go before the accept.

Comment: @EJP, I have changed the example to demonstrate the asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful treating bytes and chars as interchangeable.  Bytes are signed!

Comment: I thought of this, but it's clearly not the (only) problem.  First, zero is zero, signed or not.  Second, I wrote out the bits and don't see a pattern (beyond ~0 = -1).